# jQuery doesnt want to select elements from .load

Tags: jquery

I'v been trying to make this work, but I cannot find the solution.
Thanks.

```
//original index.php
<div class="imgContain"> </div>

//index.php after calling load.php [$('.imgContain').load('load.php');]
<div class="imgContain">
    <img class="finalimg" alt="link" src="website.com/imga546.jpg">
    <img class="finalimg" alt="green" src="website.com/imga645.jpg">
    <img class="finalimg" alt="cap" src="website.com/imga6786.jpg">
    <img class="finalimg" alt="sarge" src="website.com/imga31234.jpg">
</div>

//jQuery code I'm trying to make work
$("img[class='finalimg']").each( function(index, element){
        alert("found");   
});

//output: zero alerts
```

Here is the link to the working code, if everything is loaded from index.php and not load.php:
[working](http://jsfiddle.net/YS54N/1/)

Comment: could you explain more about what is the problem? notice that if the JS part is not wrapped in your actual code it won't work

Answer (score 2):

You need use the Document.ready and use `$("img.finalimg")` instead of `$("img[class='finalimg']")` :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("img.finalimg").each( function(index, element){
        alert("found");   
  });
})
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kK9c3/)